# How to authenticate application while making AJAX calls?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cordova, authentication

I have the following Code in AngularJs, but , how can I ensure that I am sending the authenticated app to communicate to back end?

```css
resp.get
Update = function () {
            //return $http.get(urlBase);
            return $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url: urlBase + eventList, 
                    
                    
                    });
            };
```

e.g.:
I have a RESTFUL API in Drupal for showing a list of events. To get that list of events in my hybrid app (Angular+cordova), I will make a $hhtp call. During that call, I need to send a auth code. How to do it? And how can I be sure, its from iOS or Android or Desktop?

I am thinking of using - MD5 (angular md5) for this. But, what are the encode and decode method for it which will be supported by both AJS and Drupal at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need json web token authentication
https://github.com/easystreet3/angular-drupal
https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt

Comment: Yes, I am interacting with Drupal APIs. but I want simple $http technique which would send some API key for authentication instead of Drupal

Comment: Can't we integrate $http methods for drupal?

Comment: For this, now to make it simple m thinking of simple token key -   am thinking of using - MD5 (angular md5) for this. But, what are the encode and decode method for it which will be supported by both AJS and Drupal at the backend.